# Why is した used in "茶道の楽しさは、ゆっくりした時間が味わえることです"

Tags: grammar

> 茶道の楽しさは、ゆっくりした時間が味わえることです

Why is it した and not する?

Comment: ゆっくりした時間 is "slow time", whereas ゆっくりする時間 means "time to relax", "time to slow down", etc.